# vba excel looping thru an array

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a rookie at vba.
I created a solution that works on a micro basis, but can't get the same code to run when I add additional parameters to that code. 
I created a multiple choice quiz with answer cells which test against the answers on a separate (hidden) sheet.  An adjacent cell shows Yes or No response.  That functionality which I researched on the web works well.  I'm trying to clear.contents for all the cells so that the user can complete the quiz, clear all responses to give it another go.

I have 395 questions which I created code to clear "Range("B2").ClearContents"
My subroutine has 395 such commands and takes 45-60 seconds.  I'm looking for a more efficient solution.  I don't want to clear the entire column only the 395 non-adjacent cells which have user input.

```
Sub Test_Clear()
Range("B2,B5,B7,B9,B11").ClearContents
End Sub
```

My list of cells is on Sheet2  D1:D395  Each cell in D1:D395 lists a cell on Sheet1 which I want to clear (i.e. B6, B11, B17, B22, B35 etc.) How can I reference those cells on Sheet2 and perform the ClearContents?

Comment: To be fair, I haven't used `.ClearContents`, but what's stopping you from just using a fully qualified a declaration? `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("insertRangeHere").ClearContents`

Comment: I love it when quizzes have a hidden sheet with the answers :]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Thanks Joe,  So sorry if I broke protocol.  Some kind participants did give me some direction.  I searched multiple web resources and could not find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

While you could just hard code your list in VBA instead of your `Sheet2` range, here is how you could reference that list of cells in `sheet2` and clear the contents all at once:

```
Sub clearall()
    Dim rngCell, listCells As String
    For Each rngCell In Sheet2.Range("D1:D395").Cells
        If listCell <> "" Then listCell = listCell & "," & rngCell.Value Else listCell = rngCell.Value
    Next
    Sheet2.Range(listCell).ClearContents

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for helping.  I'm using Excel 2010 if that makes a difference.

Comment: I used the code you posted and got error: "Run-time error '1004'  Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed.  I'm using a button click to run the macro.  button located on Sheet1, cells to be cleared located on Sheet1.  D1:D395 located on sheet2  Appears I need reference

Comment: Did you change the relevant parts of this code to point to your correct sheets? I'm guessing it's bombing on the `Sheet2.Range(listCell).clearContents` line. Hit the debug button and see what the value is stored in `listCell` variable in your `Locals` window in VBE. It should be a comma seperated list of cell references that is built from the `D1:D395` range of Sheet2.

Comment: Hmmm?  Yes, both Range statements indicate Sheet2.  The local window shows the comma separated listing of applicable cells to be cleared. What points the ClearContents statement to the cells on Sheet1?  It is the active sheet when the button is clicked.

Comment: You would want to change `Sheet2.Range(listCell).ClearContents` to `Sheet1.Range(listCell).clearContents` That's telling excel "In Sheet1 there is a Range of cells denoted by the list of cells in `listCell`. Clear the contents of those cells in that sheet"

Comment: I cannot seem to resolve this.  This code still throws an 1004 error.

Comment: Help Please?   This code throws a 1004 error.                                       Sub clearall()
Dim rngCell, listCells As String
    For Each rngCell In Sheet2.Range("D1:D395").Cells
        If listCell <> "" Then listCell = listCell & "," & rngCell.Value Else listCell = rngCell.Value
    Next
Sheet1.Range(listCell).ClearContents

End Sub                                                                                                           When the code runs listCell contains the string of cell addresses to be cleared.  The target cells are on Sheet1.

Comment: Does the list of cells in `listCell` look like a list of cells once the `Sheet1.Range(listCell).clearContents` code runs?  Put a breakpoint on that line (using your f9 key) and run the macro and see what's happening. Is that the line that it's debugging on or does it debug before that?

Comment: Yes, that line.  listCell shows "B6,B12,B18.... consistent with the cell addresses to be cleared.  From the

Comment: Are there any values in `listCell` that are blank. Like: `B6,B12,B18,,,B26,'?

Comment: Not sure how to see past what shows in Locals window. Every cell in Range(D1:D395) has a value.  listCell appears to contain those, but Locals window only shows me the first 20 or so values

Comment: toss a line above that one that is erroring: `debug.print listCell` and make sure your immediate window is showing. It will dump the whole thing in the output there.

Comment: I really appreciate your patient assistance.  It shows all the cell addresses to clear.

Comment: Do you have any VBA events firing on that sheet that might be getting kicked off when we clear the contents? Is `Sheet2` definitely the right one. Is "Sheet2" the name of the tab on excel front end. For fun, try switching that code to `Sheets("Sheet2").Range(listCell).clearContents`.

Comment: Get Error 9 subscript out of range.   Sheet1 is where the cells to clear are located.  I note the variable listCells is declared, but listCell called in the code.

Comment: The declaration is a mistake for sure, but it won't effect the code. Feel free to change it though. If we are clearing cells in a tab named "Sheet1" then do a `Sheets("Sheet1").Range(listCells).clearContents`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to clear the cells in column A which have something in them you could use this

```
Sheet1.Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
'or
Sheet1.Range("A1:A395").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
```

Comment: Thx. my intent is to clear only specific cells in the column.  If they happen to be blank don't want that to throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

The VBA `Join` function can be used to join values into string, and the Excel `Transpose` function is needed to "flip" the column values 2D array to a 1D row values array:

```
stringAdress = Join([Transpose(Sheet2!D1:D395)], ",")

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(stringAdress).ClearContents
```

If any of the cells in the `Sheet2!D1:D395` range are blank, the above will result in error.

In Excel 2016, the [`TextJoin`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXTJOIN-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) function can be used to ignore empty cells (not tested):

```
stringAdress = [TextJoin(",", True, Sheet2!D1:D395)]

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(stringAdress).ClearContents
```

Comment: Yeah,  some of the target cells may be blank.